# How to force an Access query datasheet to refresh its data

Tags: ms-access, select, refresh, ms-access-2013

I am new on access and what I am trying to do is a select with a criteria so I created a query with the wizard and seted the criteria with a text from a form ([Forms]![Form1]![Transacao]) and created a button to run the query at the first time works great but when I type something else and click the button the datas do not refresh. What I have to do to refresh? I've tryed to add refresh on the event click of the button and did not work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When you "run the query", is it in a subform or are you opening the query's default datasheet (i.e. the same window that open when you run the query from the Access Navigation Pane)?

Comment: I Think I am using the default datasheet, because I did not change anythig just add two texts and a button in the form and once I click in the button open a tab that is probably the one where the query was crated. I probably do not Know how to open in a new subform. I only used the wizard to create a query and only add a event on the button

Comment: Another question, did you write VBA (Visual Basic) code for the button, or is the button running a macro?

Comment: Next time, including details like I am asking is best.  When you say "Created a button to run..." you should include just what that means... a macro or VBA code.  If you are not certain, then I suggest researching and learning the difference--it will help you in Access as well as asking better questions.

Answer (score 6):

In Access, a query is usually opened in a default Datasheet view.  This default datasheet is contained in a window (or tab) that is only accessible using Macros or `DoCmd` in VBA.

Once a query window is open, its data will not necessarily update automatically when new records are added to the underlying table(s).  The datasheet needs to be "**requeried**".  (Incidentally, the term "refresh" is usually reserved to mean "redrawing" a window on the screen and has nothing to do with the data.  This is especially the case in programming and development environments which deal with data and drawing/painting windows and controls on the screen.)

Here is one way to force a query to update its data (when open in its default datasheet view):

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryName"
DoCmd.Requery
```

Calling OpenQuery should also activate the query window if it is already open.  If you find that the windows does not activate, you can also call `DoCmd.SelectObject acQuery, "QueryName"` before `DoCmd.Requery`.

The DoCmd methods correspond to Macro actions, so if the query is activated by a Macro, just add the **`Requery`** action to the macro *after* the `OpenQuery` or `SelectObject` actions.  Leave the `Control Name` parameter of the `Requery` action *blank* to force the entire query to updated.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit stale at this point, but since I couldn't find a suitable answer to this question and the above answer didn't work for me (and still hasn't been accepted), I thought I'd offer my solution for those few poor saps still stuck developing applications in Access. My use case was slightly different (changing the underlying SQL of a query, then opening/refreshing it), but the same principle could be applied. The gist is to first [check to see if the query is open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/miscellaneous/detect-whether-an-object-is-open) and close it if it is. Then open it up again.

To do this, paste this code into a VBA module:

```
Public Function open_or_refresh_query(query_name As String, Optional sql_str As String = "")
' Refresh or open an existing query
' query_name: Name of the query
' sql_str: optional new SQL string if changing the underlying SQL. If not given,
'   the query will open with its existing SQL string

    On Error GoTo err_handler

    Dim qdf As QueryDef
    ' Loop through each query in the DB and find the one of interest by name
    For Each qdf In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        If qdf.Name = query_name Then
            ' If the query is open, close it
            If SysCmd(acSysCmdGetObjectState, acQuery, query_name) <> 0 Then
                DoCmd.Close acQuery, query_name, acSaveNo
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next qdf

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs(query_name)

    ' Reset the SQL if new SQL string was given
    If Len(sql_str) > 0 Then qdf.sql = sql_str

    ' Close the QueryDef object to release resources
    qdf.Close

    ' Open the query in default datasheet view
    DoCmd.OpenQuery query_name

exit_function:
    Exit Function

err_handler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
    Resume exit_function

End Function
```

At this point you could call this function from any other VBA code in your project. To open/refresh a query from a macro as the OP wanted to do, create a new macro and add a [RunCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/runcode-macro-action) action with `open_or_refresh_query("my_query")` in the *Function Name* field, changing `my_query` to the name of your query.

Answer (score 0):

If DoCmd.Requery isn't working, another option is to close the query then re-open it. The code below will run without error whether the query is already open or already closed.

DoCmd.Close acQuery, "QueryName", acSaveNo

DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryName", acViewNormal, acReadOnly